# Timeout after 6000ms after submitting a transaction

Tags: stellar-core, docker

Whenever I submit a transaction I get a timeout error (after 60 secs). The server is a docker quickstart image in standalone mode. To solve the issue I am have to run the image with -e LOG_LEVEL="debug". 
In this case I get the reply in a few seconds as expected.

My question is how can I fix this issue without using LEVEL="debug" which I cannot use in production?

Configuration that has the problem:

```
docker run -d --rm -it -p "8000:8000" -v "/dev_data:/opt/stellar" --name stellar_dev stellar/quickstart --standalone
```

Configuration that solves the problem:

```
docker run -d --rm -it -e LOG_LEVEL="debug" -p "8000:8000" -v "/dev_data:/opt/stellar" --name stellar_dev stellar/quickstart --standalone
```

Comment: Could you confirm the version of your Horizon? It is reported that Horizon v0.15.4 could ease quite much of this issue.

Comment: @cesarm horizon_version: v0.14.1, core_version: v10.0.0

Comment: as the update on fixing the acclaimed issue is made at v0.15.4, you may consider making an upgrade to see any improvement...

Comment: @cesarm it works like a charm! the problem disappeared after upgrading to v0.15.4

Answer (score 0):

I am digging on this problem and I got some conclusion. log_level='debug' isn't solution about this. The key is horizon was restarted. I don't know the exact problem.

If you want to make `timeout` situation, you restart horizon, PostgreSQL, stellar-core sequentially in supervisorctl.

Comment: It seems that I'm facing with this issue actually https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/305

Comment: Yes, I saw 0.15.4 commit log. https://github.com/stellar/go/commit/1a536e3bd0b45febf3cbb86c6e39bab4450374e1#diff-0295088b7d58b598f16b230b7fef7827
This is why restarting horizon solve the problem.